# Redirecting to a blank page after document.forms[0].submit()

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a simple HTML page that logs into another website by creating a form with a "POST" method and a URL as the action, along with a username and password. After "document.forms[0].submit()", I want a blank page to be displayed instead of URL. I have tried the 4 commands below after "document.forms[0].submit()", but it just momentarily redirects to "about:blank" before redirecting to the URL. The code is as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/login">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="xxx" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="xxx" />
</form>
```

```
document.forms[0].submit();
    //window.location.replace("about:blank")
    //location.href="about:blank";
    //window.open("about:blank", "_self");
location.replace("about:blank");
```

Is there another way to redirect to the blank page on a more permanent basis?

Comment: Potential to use an ajax request to the other site rather than a form submit, though CORS could be an issue.  You could also possibly `target="anIframe"` with the form and potentially redirect to the about blank when the iframe loads.

Comment: it is not logical, it allows to send the form indefinitely, in addition to deploying as many new pages on the browser